# Stop Auto increment id ,if record fail to insert in mysql

Tags: mysql

I used mysql for development.when I insert wrong data in my table. It show me error.but still auto increment id get increment by 1 ,how to stop increment id by 1 if error occurred.

Comment: Not possible. But in my view auto increment id should not have any business meaning.

Comment: It resolves the great chance of assigning the same id to more than one row. You can't stop it from incrementing. Unless you turn off `Auto Increment`. Which I don't recommend in anyway.